# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: topojson is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new  at d3. I can't render a US  map, could you have a look?

https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/BaZYewv

```
d3.json(COUNTIES)
  .then( data =>  {
   let  states = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.states);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TopoJSON was never part of any D3 bundle. Therefore, you have to reference it, like:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
```

In the CodePen, "Add Package" will create:

```
import * as topojson from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/topojson@3.0.2";
```

(and now you'll have brand new errors...)

Comment: prolly accidently deleted it. but still see nothing 0 errors https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/BaZYewv

Comment: Well, that was the error in your question title and in the console, which was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using webpack, install dependencies

```
npm i topojson-server topojson-client -y
```

Then at the JS file

```js
import * as topojsonServer from 'topojson-server/dist/topojson-server'
import * as topojsonClient from 'topojson-client/dist/topojson-client'

//...

const topoJSON = topojsonServer.topology([geoJsonFeatureCollection], 1e4)
const neighbors = topojsonClient.neighbors(topoJSON.objects[0].geometries)
```